# Azure B2C Seamless account migration base policies

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Just getting started with a migration of an existing legacy (local database) IDP to Azure B2C. I want to use something similar to the seamless user migration ( https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/seamless-account-migration/policy ) custom policy.  Looking at the B2C community GitHub repository, it is missing the base policies.  Any idea where I can find those base policy examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre requisites are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started

Or use my tool to automate it: https://aka.ms/iefsetup